# Python: decrease running time of for loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I want to calculate APRU for several countries.

```
country_list = ['us','gb','ca','id']

count = {}
for i in country_list:
    count[i] = df_day_country[df_day_country.isin([i])]
    count[i+'_reverse'] = count[i].iloc[::-1]
    for j in range(1,len(count[i+'_reverse'])): 
        count[i+'_reverse']['count'].iloc[j] = count[i+'_reverse']['count'][j-1:j+1].sum()
    for k in range(1,len(count[i])): 
        count[i][revenue_sum].iloc[k] = count[i][revenue_sum][k-1:k+1].sum()

    count[i]['APRU'] = count[i][revenue_sum] / count[i]['count'][0]/100
```

After that, I will create 4 dataframes: df_us, df_gb, df_ca, df_id that show each country's APRU.

But the size of dataset is large. The running time is extremely slow after the country list become larger. So is there a way to decrease the running time?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Input (`df_day_country`) and expected output?

Comment: It looks like you want to do rolling sums with the inner loops? more optimal to create the corresponding `reverse` columns on the original dataframe and perform the rolling sums accordingly - you seem to have a central window of 3?.

You are creating lots of dataframes of the same length of the original dataframe.

Comment: where is this df_day_country from? can you share a sample data?

Comment: Just curious, what's APRU? A quick google gives only ARPU.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)

Your code thus becomes

```
from numba import njit

country_list = ['us','gb','ca','id']

@njit
def count(country_list):
  count = {}
  for i in country_list:
      count[i] = df_day_country[df_day_country.isin([i])]
      count[i+'_reverse'] = count[i].iloc[::-1]
      for j in range(1,len(count[i+'_reverse'])): 
          count[i+'_reverse']['count'].iloc[j] = count[i+'_reverse']['count'][j-1:j+1].sum()
      for k in range(1,len(count[i])): 
          count[i][revenue_sum].iloc[k] = count[i][revenue_sum][k-1:k+1].sum()

      count[i]['APRU'] = count[i][revenue_sum] / count[i]['count'][0]/100
  return count
```

Numba makes python loops a lot faster and is in the process of being integrated into the more heavy duty python libraries like scipy. Deffinetly give this a look.

Comment: @jezrael given the lack of a complete running example of what the asker is trying to do I did not. Nevertheless i've found the question to be, on a broader level, on the topic of making python for loops more efficient, which reminded me of numba and i think the asker could use it for his purpose

Comment: I ask because in my opinion idea with numba is nice, but code is necessary change more.

Comment: I doubt this will make much difference, numba doesn't know much about pandas, and all the strange indexing is going to kill it.  you have to be pretty careful with your code for numba to help much

Comment: @SamMason Numba is one of the proposed solutions in this doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html That said I agree it's not super straightforward to use in this case, and can be hit or miss. Still I'd consider trying it given the nested for loops

Comment: yes, but if you notice all the applications are "simple" functions that don't touch the pandas dataframe.  they're all just numpy or plain math operations

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, from your code and variable names, it looks like you are trying to compute average:

```
# toy data set:
country_list = ['us','gb']

np.random.seed(1)
datalen=10
df_day_country = pd.DataFrame({'country': np.random.choice(country_list, datalen),
                               'count': np.random.randint(0,100, datalen),
                               'revenue_sum': np.random.uniform(0,100,datalen)})


df_day_country['APRU'] =  (df_day_country.groupby('country',group_keys=False)
                            .apply(lambda x: x['revenue_sum']/x['count'].sum())
                          )
```

Output:

```
+----------+--------+--------------+------------+----------+
| country  | count  | revenue_sum  |    APRU    |          |
+----------+--------+--------------+------------+----------+
|       0  | gb     |          16  | 20.445225  | 0.150333 |
|       1  | gb     |           1  | 87.811744  | 0.645675 |
|       2  | us     |          76  | 2.738759   | 0.011856 |
|       3  | us     |          71  | 67.046751  | 0.290246 |
|       4  | gb     |           6  | 41.730480  | 0.306842 |
|       5  | gb     |          25  | 55.868983  | 0.410801 |
|       6  | gb     |          50  | 14.038694  | 0.103226 |
|       7  | gb     |          20  | 19.810149  | 0.145663 |
|       8  | gb     |          18  | 80.074457  | 0.588783 |
|       9  | us     |          84  | 96.826158  | 0.419161 |
+----------+--------+--------------+------------+----------+
```